# Will the Olympic skins (+ other future event skins) be buyable after the event is over?

Tags: overwatch

There's brand new skins in overwatch, and they are event themed.

Will they be just gone after the event (those who have it keep it, those who don't are screwed...)

It should be one of 3 scenarios

1. Skin can still be got in boxes
2. Skin cannot be got in boxes but can be bought with gold
3. Skin is unavailable to any who dont have it, like with the founders skins

Comment: I won't answer this question because I believe it's off topic, but Blizzard have stated that these cosmetics won't be available outside of the event loot boxes, and that this is going to be a yearly event. Next year it might or might not be possible to obtain the same skins again, in addition to new ones.

Comment: I voted to reopen. Don't think this is about unreleased content. It's about the loot boxes which are currently available. That's released content. They've said officially they're only available for the event.

Comment: @DCShannon The question is explicitly asking about what will happen in the future.  We have nothing in-game to base any sort of answers on, leading this to the exact same issue as unreleased games.  Voting to leave closed.

Comment: Now we do. Should be reopened.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Game director [Jeff Kaplan talks about seasonal items](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLQPx78ntYM):

Seasonal/Event items will only be available through loot boxes earned during the event period and you won't be able to get them after the event ends. You won't be able to buy them with gold or money either. You just have to wait for next season if it returns.

Note about the new Anniversary event:

This event may be more unique than the others, but the temporariness of the event and its items remains the same.

[Source](http://playoverwatch.com/en-us/events/anniversary):

> You’ll earn Anniversary Loot Boxes as you play, plus pick up a free box when you log in between May 23 and June 12, 2017. Anniversary Loot Boxes are also available for purchase—**but they’ll be locked away after the event ends.**

Blizzard announced that the Summer Games event will be returning with some new and some old skins further indicating that these will be reoccurring events with annual opportunities to acquire skins etc.

Comment: Also, from the [Overwatch blog](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20216482): While any Summer Games item you unlock will be yours forever, the collection will be heading back into the vault on August 22 when the event concludes. So, if you’ve got your eye on something specific, there's no time to lose!